# No puedo convertir py a exe sin el símbolo del sistema

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Estoy tratando de convertir un script de Python en un archivo ejecutable sin el símbolo del sistema. Traté de hacer `pyinstaller --onefile --icon=totalpower.ico --windowed PowerShare.py` y no funciona.También intenté hacerlo con `-w` y `--noconsole.`

Una parte de mi código:

```
"""
cmdGen.py genera comandos ffmpeg para grabar tu pantalla

"""
import os

class cmdGen:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fps = 60
        self.source = "desktop"
        self.encoder = 'mpeg4'
        self.hwaccel = None
        self.drawMouse = 1
        self.enableWebcam = False
        self.audList = 0
    def config(self,
                fps=None,source=None,encoder=None,
                hwaccel='unchanged',drawMouse=None,
                webcam=None,audList=None):
        if fps: self.fps = fps
        if source: self.source = source
        if encoder: self.encoder = encoder
        if hwaccel != 'unchanged': self.hwaccel = hwaccel
        if drawMouse: self.drawMouse = 0 if not self.drawMouse else 1
        if webcam: self.enableWebcam = bool(webcam)
        if audList: self.audList = audList
    def setSource(self,isWindow,windowName=""):
        if not isWindow:
            self.source = "desktop"
        else:
            self.source = "title="+windowName
    def setFps(self,fps):
        self.fps = fps
    def setEncode(self,encoder):
        self.encoder = encoder
    def getCmd(self,filename):
        print("ACK")
        finalCmd = ["ffmpeg.exe","-f","gdigrab"]
        finalCmd.extend(['-i',self.source])
        finalCmd.extend(['-framerate',str(self.fps)])
        finalCmd.extend(['-c:v',self.encoder])
        if self.encoder == 'mpeg4':
            finalCmd.extend(['-q:v','7'])
        if self.hwaccel: 
            finalCmd.extend(['-hwaccel',self.hwaccel])
        finalCmd.extend(['-draw_mouse',str(self.drawMouse)])
        finalCmd.extend(["-y", filename])
        print(finalCmd)
        return finalCmd
    def getCvtCmd(self,filename):
            # if self.rcchecked.get():
            #     self.mergeProcess = subprocess.Popen(args= ["ffmpeg","-i",'tmp/tmp.mkv','-i','tmp/tmp.wav','-i','tmp/webcamtmp.mkv','-filter_complex','[2:v] scale=640:-1 [inner]; [0:0][inner] overlay=0:0 [out]',"-shortest",'-map','[out]','-y',"ScreenCaptures/"+self.filename])
            # else:
            #     self.mergeProcess = subprocess.Popen(args= ["ffmpeg","-i",'tmp/tmp.mkv','-i','tmp/tmp.wav',"-shortest",'-y',"ScreenCaptures/"+self.filename], startupinfo=startupinfo)
        print("ACK")
        finalCmd = ["ffmpeg.exe"]
        finalCmd.extend(['-i','tmp/tmp.mkv'])
        for i in range(len(self.audList)):
            finalCmd.extend(['-i','tmp/tmp_'+str(i)+'.wav'])
        if len(self.audList) > 0:
            finalCmd.extend(['-filter_complex','amerge=inputs='+str(len(self.audList)),'-ac',str(len(self.audList))])
        # finalCmd.extend(['-c:v',self.encoder])
        if self.enableWebcam:
            finalCmd.extend(['-i','tmp/webcamtmp.mkv','-filter_complex','[2:v] scale=640:-1 [inner]; [0:0][inner] overlay=0:0 [out]','-map','[out]'])
        finalCmd.extend(['-shortest'])
        finalCmd.extend(["-y", filename])
        print(finalCmd)
        return finalCmd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cg = cmdGen()
    cg.setEncode("h264_nvenc")
    cg.setFps(60)
    cg.setSource(False)
    print(cg.getCmd("tmp"))
```

Yo estoy usando una grabadora de video pero no quiero que el usuario vea el símbolo del sistema. Como dije en el comentario, este código genera comandos ffmpeg para filmar el desktop. Necesito terminar lo antes posible porque el proyecto está retrasado.¿Alguien sabe lo que podría ser?

Comment: ¿Qué sistema operativo estás utilizando?

Comment: Sistema Windows @dnlb

Comment: Esta libreria te incluye un interfaz grafica https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/

Comment: He usado este y no funcionó

Comment: Hola Gabriel, ¿qué módulos usas? ¿por casualidad usas subprocess o multiprocessing?¿cualquier otra funcionalidad que requiera entrada/salida estándar o genere una instancia de CMD por si misma?

Comment: subprocess,os,threading,time,wave,pyaudio y tkinter

Comment: Creo que si @FJSevilla.Voy añadir una parte de mi codigo.